# Looping through arrays. Rainbow Text Exercise

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

Need help. I attached the image of the question, This is the image of the code:

[image]

```
// This is the given code:

const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];
```

```
// I written these:

const spans = document.querySelector('h1 span');

for(let rainbow of spans){
    spans.style.color = " ";
}
```

Comment: But what do you need help with? There's no question. Also please [no images of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: You need to apply style to `rainbow` instead of `spans`. Also in your case better use `for .. in` loop because you need index, like this: `for (let i in spans) spans[i].style.color = colors[i]`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `document.querySelectorAll('h1 span')` to get all `span` item.

Then you can use `Array.forEach` to get character and index. Then you map the index to the `colors` array.

```js
// This is the given code:
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet'];

// I written these:
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('h1 span');
spans.forEach((item, index) => {
  item.style.color = colors[index];
})
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>R</span>
  <span>A</span>
  <span>I</span>
  <span>N</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>W</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. 
Is there any other way rather than forEach to solve this problem??
I'm a beginner, So concepts in loops, arrays and functions are little hard for me. I have many questions related these-

Comment: @Rasik07 You can use `for (const index in spans)` to go through all of `span` items.

Answer (score 0):

```
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; 
//PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:

const letters = document.querySelectorAll('span')enter code here

let count = 0

for (let letter of letters){
    letter.style.color = colors[count]
    count += 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:

const allh=document.querySelectorAll('span');
let i=0;
for(let h of allh){
    h.style.color = colors[i++];
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Rainbow</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
    <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <!--DON'T TOUCH THIS FILE PLEASE!-->
    <h1>
        <span>R</span>
        <span>A</span>
        <span>I</span>
        <span>N</span>
        <span>B</span>
        <span>O</span>
        <span>W</span>
    </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74825971/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers  in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

const colors = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'indigo', 'violet']; //PLEASE DON'T CHANGE THIS LINE!

//YOU CODE GOES HERE:
let v = document.querySelectorAll("span")

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++ ){
v[i].style.color = colors[i];

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).